# accessing all data in View (created in database) from Meteor

Tags: mysql, meteor, meteorite

I am using the MySQL version of Meteor (which is supposed to behave the same as the MongoDB version for this purpose), and am trying to access a view which exists in my database.  When Meteor starts I get:

```
loaded:test_view
test_view is a view
```

But when I access the data in this view I only get a single row back, instead of all 100-odd rows that exist in the database.  Has anyone else had similar issues?
My javascript is:

```
var testView = new Meteor.Table('test_view');
Template.mpiInstalls.testviews = function() {
   return testView.find({});
};
```

And my related html is:

```
<template name='mpiInstalls'>
  <div id="test">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>timestamp</th>
          <th>username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each textviews}}
        {{> _testview}}
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<template name='_testview'>
  <tr>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td>{{start_timestamp}}</td>
    <td>{{http_username}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: The [`meteor-sql`](https://github.com/drorm/meteor-sql) package is 10 months old. I assume this is what you're using; there is no official "MySQL version" of Meteor. Significant, breaking changes have occurred to Meteor since then. Your best bet for using SQL with Meteor is waiting for after 1.0 - it's on the roadmap: https://trello.com/c/Gf6YxFp2/42-sql-support

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm using.  I (probably wrongly) assumed that since the basic table/collection accesses still work, things like accessing basic views would also work.